# Can the Healer Feat be used through an Imp familiar with a healer's kit?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, warlock, familiars, healing

While familiars have been commonly used to deliver potions of healing because "your familiar acts independently of you, but it always obeys your commands" and "can take other actions as normal". "Additionally, as an action, you can see through your familiar's eyes and hear what it hears until the start of your next turn".

Since "when you cast a spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver the spell as if it had cast the spell", shouldn't I be able to use the Healer Feat through the imp familiar with a healer's kit because it has hands and there's some touching going on here?

My goal is to create an imp familiar combat medic that can charge into battle to try to stabilize fallen frontline fighters while allowing the squishy warlock to hang back in safety, but still offer aid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### RAW : No

As you've correctly quoted, the imp familiar can deliver spells with a range of touch. The Healer feat isn't a spell, so it does not qualify for this ability.

The imp is its own creature with its own stats and abilities. It does not benefit from your features or abilities unless stated otherwise.

#### Your DM can always rule otherwise

Your idea for a character sounds quite original, so if your DM doesn't find it to be unbalanced, they could decide to allow it.

Talk to them about this, and about your combat medic imp concept. Even if they disapprove of applying Healer to the imp's actions, they might find another mechanic or workaround to make your idea work. It could be through allowing this with additional cost on your action economy, or through a unique action for the imp. In any case, it's all up to them.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and I have a few clarifying questions. While the "imp is its own creature with its own stats and abilities", when it is being completely controlled by the warlock, the imp is able to deliver the touch spells without having the spell casting ability. So I'm having difficulty seeing how that is much different from the imp being controlled to bandage a wound? My analogy would be if I could use the Healer Feat with prosthetic hands and Ersatz Eyes, I should be able to use the imp's hands and eyes as a tool as well. Thoughts?

Comment: Another example of this situation may arise using the dominate spells which state that "you can use your action to take total and precise control of the target". If they did exactly what I said to do with "total and precise control", it would seem not much different than me doing it myself. What do you think?

Comment: @wpigrad if we take a logical approach to this, things like the Healer feat show not only knowledge, but also muscle memory and other technical skills, which the imp does not have (telling it what to do doesn't mean it knows how to do it). Furthermore, the imp can only deliver your touch spells, meaning they are nothing more than a source from where you can channel your magic. They are not casting the spell, and you are not controlling them. You are simply channeling your magic into them thanks to your familiar's link, and ordering them to touch the enemy.

Comment: If you could take precise control of your familiar, I believe it's up to debate. I can think of multiple compelling arguments for and against this point. But it's probably worth another question entirely.

Comment: The imp can deliver a touch spell for you because it has an ability that *specifically* allows it to do that. It doesn't mean the imp can stand in for your hands under any and all circumstances, it just means your special magical bond with the thing lets you channel magic to it under very specific circumstances.  The Healer feat isn't about channeling magical energy in any way, so I don't see how it connects.

Comment: @Matthieu - This may be a big ask, but could you share the books and pages that you used to reference the RAW for this topic? There are so many books and I don't have them all, but I think this would be helpful for me to continue this discussion to clarify my concerns. Thanks.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym - I am thinking about what a combat medic could do in the field in 6 seconds to stabilize a wounded soldier. They could apply a tourniquet, stuff gauze or coagulant into the wound, or wrap up an arm or leg in a splint. This does not involve more than sight and touch. In real life I believe I could walk you through the process if we were next to each other and I did not have use of my hands. Just trying to clarify my position. Controlling the familiar seems like a similar situation. Thoughts?

Comment: On a realism side, I think walking somebody through something is always going to be slower and less accurate than doing it yourself.  But on the game side, *you* have a feat, the imp does not.  It's just not how the game works.  If you start taking feats and class features and trying to decide which ones you can share with another character by talking to them, you're off the map almost immediately.

Comment: @wpigrad I used nothing more than the text you quoted and the principle that in 5e, [there are no secret rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/107647/77044). The second part also refers implicitely to [rule 0](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/102511/77044).